# SharePoint Online - page templates

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a need to create page templates with fixed sections/web parts similar to the on-prem versions of publishing page layouts and pages.  What is the recommended option on SPO? Publishing site templates are still available on SPO. Is that future proof given MSFT is advocating to migrate publishing pages to modern pages. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern pages is recommended by Microsoft. So I would suggest you creat template for modern pages in SharePoint Online.

That's very easy, you could refer to the documentation:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/page-templates-in-sharepoint-faa92408-0c84-4e3d-8460-3c28065e7873

Comment: Thanks Michael. The emphasis is on "fixed sections/web parts".  We are trying to enforce a strict layout and with the modern pages, users can add/remove sections/webparts.  Is there a way to lock it down?

Comment: No, you can not lock it down for modern pages.